# AWS Parameter Store from older version of ssm sdk (1.11.68)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-nifi, aws-ssm

How can i read parameters using aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.68 . Unfortunately i cannot upgrade it as it is being bundled as part of NiFi. And my code is part of the Custom Processor.

The only option i see is invoking a REST Call not using ADS SDK at all and  pass the credentials.

Is there any easier way or does AWS SDK provides option of making a custom REST Call ? That way i don't need to extract the credentials and pass as part of my REST Call invocation.

Thanks

Comment: You can always have properties in your custom processor and use it to read the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon publishes the AWS Systems Manager API. This API is very easy to use and the only challenge is the Signature Version 4 Signing Process. They good thing about signing is that there are a lot of code examples out there. I have not written SSM API code in Java, but I have in Scala and Python. The process is pretty easy.

Your credentials are used as part of the signing process and building the HTTP request. The API itself does not care about your credentials.

Start with the API Reference:
[AWS Systems Manager API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)

The look at the signing process:
[Signature Version 4 Signing Process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html)

Comment: As far as I can tell, these links are pointing to the latest docs for the API, not to the older 1.11.68 version.

Comment: @MarkMeuer This question is a year old. I do not control the content of AWS links. If you have better links, please post another answer to update this thread.

Comment: I understand.  My point was that the OP was explicitly asking for help with an older version of the API.  Almost all of the examples and documentation that I've been able to find don't work for the version of the SDK the OP is discussing.  I've got the same problem, so I don't have updated links.

Comment: @MarkMeuer - again, I cannot do anything about AWS changing the content (updating) of a link. It is standard practice to update pages with relevant information or whatever the company wants. The answer was current at the time posted. My suggestion is to create a new question.